# Authenticate D2L Valence without Returning a Query String

Tags: authentication, desire2learn, valence

Please forgive my ignorance if I'm overlooking something quite simple.  But I am wondering how I can go about authenticating to the LMS with Valence API without the authentication returning a query string.  I have noted that in the Getting Started Example after authentication against the valence.desire2learn.com LMS instance, you are returned to the getting started app but the URL now has the User ID and the User Key in the URL as query strings (x_a, x_b).  Is there a way to authenticate so that the end user never sees these ID/Key combination.  My concern is that if someone were to bookmark a site on a computer, they could gain access to a User ID/Key pair that is of an elevated privilege.  This, combined with the fact that a user could retrieve an AppID/AppKey pair from the authentication URL that is generated could spell disaster.  Armed with a user's keys and app keys, one could program any number of malicious attacks.  I am certain that D2L would have thought of this issue and thus why I feel perhaps my lack of sleep is getting in the way of seeing a simple solution.

If anyone has insight into this matter it would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Desire2Learn intends its Getting Started example application to serve only as an educational tool, designed to help developers learn about, understand, and become more comfortable with the authentication protocol used by the Valence Learning Framework APIs. As such, it will reveal information that users would not normally see in a typical setup. You should not use the Getting Started sample as a reference application for best practices around building production applications, especially with respect to how you should handle application and user credentials. For an example of how to build a production-grade application, please take a look at the Book Widget sample. You can find the [application](https://github.com/Desire2Learn-Valence/sample-bookwidget) and [test code](https://github.com/Desire2Learn-Valence/sample-remote-plugins-test-service) for the Book Widget sample on Desire2Learn's GitHub project site. This sample demonstrates the current best practices about how you should handle application and user credentials, and it also illustrates how to implement a basic LTI Tool Provider service.